# Сравнение запроса пользователя с ms[i].fio

Tags: c, файлы, структуры, сравнение

Где может быть ошибка?

Проблема в выводе телефона по фамилии абонента. А именно не работает сравнение запроса пользователя с ms[i].fio.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h> //для getch()
#include<clocale> //для локализации
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
    char familiya[15];
    struct ABONENT {
        char fio[21];
        int tel;
        int god;
    };
    FILE *file;
    struct ABONENT ms[300];
    int i = 0; //очередной элемент массива
    int j;     // номер символа фамилиии
    if ((file = fopen("абоненты.txt", "r")) == NULL)
        puts("В текущем каталоге файл не найден");
    // чтение информации из файла в массив ms*
    while (!feof(file)) {
        fgets(ms[i].fio, 15, file);
        fscanf(file, "%d %d", &ms[i].tel, &ms[i].god);
        i++;
    }
    // поиск по фамилиии
    puts("Пожалуйста, введите фамилию абонента");
    int k = i; // номер последнего элемента массива ms
    for (i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= 21; j++) {
            if (ms[i].fio[j] == ' ')
                ms[i].fio[j] = '\0';
        }
    }
    gets(familiya);
    bool net = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
        if (ms[i].fio == familiya)
            printf("%d", ms[i].tel);
        net = 1;
    }
    if (net == 1)
        puts("В базе нет абонента с такой фамилией");
    getch();
}
```

При отладке, вроде бы familiya и str[i].fio совпадают:

[image]

Но результат:

[image]

Comment: отступы! У меня из глаз кровь от этого

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(i=0;i<=k;i++){
        if(ms[i].fio==familiya)
            printf("%d", ms[i].tel);
     net=1;}
```

Пологаю тут ошибка? попробуйте так

```
for(i=0;i<=k;i++){
        if(ms[i].fio==familiya)
            printf("%d", ms[i].tel) else
     net=1;}
```

Comment: о, опередил немного меня, пока я обновлял ответ :)

Comment: Большое спасибо) Но главная проблема, была в том, что всегда выводит отсутствие телефона. Наверное массивы и строки нельзя сравнивать просто друг с другом, а только по их элементам?

Comment: @AlexC, молодец! Вы сами догадались, что надо сравнивать по элементам. А пока Вы сравниваете *адреса первых элементов* 2-х массивов (естественно, они не равны).

В Вашем случае для сравнения удобно использовать функцию strcmp(). Как пользоваться прочтите сами (man 3 strcmp).

Comment: @avp, Спасибо, что напомнили о strcmp(). С ним всё работает и занимает гораздо меньше места.

Comment: Мне вот просто интересно, @AlexC и оба автора "ответов" поняли в чем **принципиальная ошибка** в этом коде?

    if (ms[i].fio == familiya)

Comment: Незнаком с "C" так что не могу сказать как она проверяет равенство массива букв, на паскалях такое сравнение ведется как для строк с окончанием на 0.

Comment: @ToRcH565, а код-то зачем писать, если с языком не знакомы?

Написали бы алгоритм (с объяснением) на паскале.

Comment: @Torch565 На паскалях? У Вирта не было в языке строк, заканчивающихся нулём. Это уже борланды из Си позаимствовали.

Comment: мне не особа интересна история языка, мне интересно как он работает на данный момент) а на данный момент в паскалях(Делфи\Лазарь\фри паскаль) строки по умолчанию - нульзаконченые строки. Пы.сы, код я и не писал а лиш указал на сразу бросающуюся в глаза ошибку.

Comment: @ToRcH565, а в любом случае логика у Вас хромает (ошибка-то  осталась). 

Надо так

    bool net = 1;
    for (i = 0; i <= k; i++) { // возможно много телефонов
        if (strcmp(ms[i].fio,familiya) == 0) {
            printf("%d", ms[i].tel);
            net = 0;
        }
    }

или так

    bool net = 1;
    for (i = 0; i <= k; i++) { // возможно только один телефон
        if (strcmp(ms[i].fio,familiya) == 0) {
            printf("%d", ms[i].tel);
            net = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

Answer (score 4):

```
for(i=0;i<=k;i++){
            if(ms[i].fio==familiya)
                printf("%d", ms[i].tel);
         net=1;}
        if(net==1)
```

Я тихонечко в сторонке посмеюсь.

```
if(ms[i].fio==familiya) //значит нашли фамилию и присвоили переменной
net=1;
```

а дальше ты пишешь

```
if(net==1)
                puts("В базе нет абонента с такой фамилией"); // а стоит написать "В базе есть абонент!"
        getch();
```

Мой маленький совет.

Проверяй что пишешь и какие условия делаешь, чтобы потом не было глупых ошибок, причем не программно, а просто своих - их ВСЕГДА найти сложнее. а код-то у тебя работает!

//upd и да у тебя переменная net всегда равна 1 :) либо добавь if else либо немного перепиши код, но наверное добавь if else в этот кусок кода

```
 if(ms[i].fio==familiya)
                    printf("%d", ms[i].tel);
               else
             net=1;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, будет 15 уважения, обязательно лайкну=)